# highlight-indentation emacs startup

Tags: emacs, elisp, config

I've been learning emacs and lisp right, so I'm sure I'm missing something, but I'm trying to get highlight-indentation to work when I start emacs.

I've got the highlight-indentation.el file in my emacs path and after startup, I can do

M-x highlight-indentation

and all works well, but how do I get this to work on startup. I thought putting

(highlight-indentation)

in my .emacs file would work, but it didn't. Is this because highlight-indentation is an interactive function?

Comment: As `highlight-indentation` is not part of standard Emacs, it would be nice if you would add a link to it.

Comment: You're right. I've added it to one of the comments below, but here it is again [highlight-indentation](https://github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is only applied to the current buffer. I would recommend using a *hook* like the following. Functions added to major mode hooks are executed when the major mode is enabled for a particular buffer.

```
(defun my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook ()
  (highlight-indentation))
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook)
```

Comment: I've got something similar to this working: (add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'highlight-indentation), but it seems to add a lot of load to emacs every time I open a file and since I didn't know anything about that hook, I figured I'd go on the hunt to see if there is a simpler cleaner way of doing it. As for your exact code, that didn't work when I put it in my .emacs file.

Comment: Hmm, seems like I just need to look into properly running hooks in emacs. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Okay, been a while, but after seeing Matt Darling's comment down below, I've figured out that my original question was sort of misleading. Although I am still learning emacs lisp, I was actually asking about getting highlight-indentation to work for all modes. For that, I needed `after-change-major-mode-hook`, allowing me to solve the problem with: 

`(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook '(lambda ()
;;        (highlight-indentation 4)))`

Answer (score 3):

highlight-indentation.el actually creates a minor mode that will automatically highlight the indentation at all times, appropriately called highlight-indentation-mode. You can see the relevant functions under the sections that say

> ;;;###autoload

namely,

> define-minor-mode highlight-indentation-mode

and

> define-minor-mode highlight-indentation-current-column-mode

To use them, add a hook like Lindydancer suggested, but instead of creating a new hook that calls the highlight-indentation function, simply write:

> (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-indentation-mode)

I kind of prefer the (rather wordy) highlight-indentation-current-column-mode, which just highlights the column the cursor is on. It's a bit cleaner, but still shows you the relationship between different levels of the code.

**Edit**: I'm two years late to updating this, but for future Internet wanderers who want to get highlight-indentation-mode working for all programming langagues, you can do this:

> (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'highlight-indentation-mode)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what the `highlight-indentation` does. Check whether its effects are not visible in the `*scratch*` buffer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the feedback. Typing:

(highlight-indentation)

and then C-x C-e just returns nil and doesn't activate the behavior that highlight-indentation offers. In case it helps, here is a link to the source code. It's actually not much: [source](https://github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs)